GrapesJS removes onclick attributes, how to prevent it to do it?
I have an image gallery with a tiny JS to display the clicked thumbnail
<img src="https://sampleimage.jpg" width="800" height="800" onclick="sendimg(this);"/>
Unfortunately GrapesJS removes the onclick attribute on rendering, and so if I save the page I lose the attribute.
<img src="https://sampleimage.jpg" width="800" height="800" />
Any idea why ?
The rest of the page is rendered and saved correctly.
I tried to add data and custom attributes, they're not removed.
It happens only for onclick attribute.
My init:
const editor = grapesjs.init({
  container: '#gjs',
  fromElement: true,
  height: '800px',
  width: 'auto',
  storageManager: false,
  parseContent: true,

 selectorManager: { componentFirst: true }

Loaded plugins:
        plugins: [
          'gjs-blocks-basic',
          'grapesjs-plugin-forms',
          'grapesjs-component-countdown',
          'grapesjs-plugin-export',
          'grapesjs-tabs',
          'grapesjs-custom-code',
          'grapesjs-touch',
          'grapesjs-parser-postcss',
          'grapesjs-tooltip',
          'grapesjs-tui-image-editor',
          'grapesjs-typed',
          'grapesjs-style-bg',
          'grapesjs-preset-webpage',
          'grapesjs-style-gradient',
          'grapesjs-blocks-flexbox',
          'grapesjs-custom-code',
          'grapesjs-plugin-ckeditor',
        ],


does the rest of the page allow for <script> tags? you could move the onclick logic there

Yes the rest of the page is unmodified. We could make some changes, but it's not ideal, a tool like that shouldnt break quite basic code like this.
